# Problem of Command Window with LIVE555 testRTSPClient project

Tags: live555, rtsp-client

I would like to implement how to capture audio from a microphone in IP (network) camera, and in real time stream it so that can listen to it live.

I was downloading and building the LIVE555 library.

I compiled the project with the testRTSPClient.cpp in the directory of the testProgs in live555 (without modifying the code).

The compile succeeds, but the command window opens and then closes immediately. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The testRTSPClient application expect an url argument.

From the [documentation](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/)

> RTSP client
>   testRTSPClient is a command-line program that shows you
>   how to open and receive media streams that are specified by a RTSP URL
>   - i.e., an URL that begins with rtsp://

You should open a console and execute something like :

```
testRTSPClient rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
```

Comment: I have a doubt related to it. When I give maybe 100 URLs one after another in the above-mentioned format, I get all the streams working. But when it comes to 10 separate terminals, each has 1 URL, I'm not able to go beyond 8 connections. After the limit the streaming crashes, saying remote connection closed.

Comment: @SleebaPaul: your problem seems quite far from the post from JS. Park. The 100 URLs are 100 times the same url ? You may post a question explaining your problem and what you tried.

Comment: I've tried to start 100 same URLs by giving them as an argument to `testRTSPClient` in a single terminal. It worked. Then I tried 10 terminals with a single URL (same URL) each. I got stuck at 8th terminal showing `connection cannot be established, remote connection lost`.

Comment: 100 time the same URL estabilsh 1 video stream